# My image texture displays correctly in material preview but not in 3D viewport

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor, 3d-view

I have applied such image textures before without any problem but with the eyes of this character I simply cannot get the image texture to appear in the 3D viewport in either Eevee or Cycles. I feel sure I have done something daft or not done something simple but I have gone over everything several times and searched online yet cannot find what I am doing wrong.
I have attached an image showing my setup.
All help appreciated.
[image: setup shown with UV and shaders]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: My guess is that you are using the wrong UV map in the material. You seem to have plenty of different UV maps going on in the last screen shot and right now "WhiteFur" is selected. Maybe it would help to put a specific UV node in the material and chose "Eyeball" as UV map or just make sure "Eyeball" is active when you assign the material?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where are you seeing 'WhiteFur' selected? The material selection in the top screen shot is 'EyeBall', the material selection in the middle screen shot is 'EyeBall' and the UV Map selected in the bottom screen shot is 'Eyeball'.

Comment: You can always try changing the parameters of the Mapping node in the second case, using the Generated socket. That could also give you some insight into the underlying problem. (But I see now this is a very old request, and I hope you have since moved on :).

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this request for any further comments since no more suggestions have been forthcoming and nothing I tried made any difference to the lack of display in the viewport. I reluctantly deleted the eyes and made new ones applying the same image texture, in the same way and they work perfectly well.
I guess I will never know what the problem was.
Thanks for looking.